# How can i change confirm message button delete in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

this my app/admin/author- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V6r0.png)
How can i change delete button in admin/authors (index)

I need change only confirm message
How can i do this?

I try:
`actions :all, :except => [:destroy]` and then add custom `actions default: true` and create custon button, and its work i get custom message, but i can't destroy some author, because when i `actions :all, :except => [:destroy]`, this delete route for deleting author

Answer (score 0):

If relying on jquery does not bother you, add this to `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.delete_link').data('confirm', 'is this what you really want?');
    /* narrow down with selector for specificity */
    $('table#index_table_authors a.delete_link').data('confirm', 'must this author really be destroyed?');
});
```

Or